# Beamer: Colorize every second column of a table

Tags: tables, beamer

I am trying to include a table in one of my beamer frames. I want every second column of this table to have a gray background. In my LaTeX-document, the following code worked:

```
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}
\newcolumntype{g}{>{\columncolor{Gray}}c}
\begin{table}[ht]
            \centering
            \begin{tabular}{c|g|c|g|c|g}
                5.35 & 0.35 & 5.61 & -0.39 & 6.84 & -0.16 \\
                5.45 & 0.45 & 5.52 & -0.48 & 6.84 & -0.16 \\
                5.45 & 0.45 & 5.51 & -0.49 & 6.96 & -0.04 \\
                5.45 & 0.45 & 5.63 & -0.37 & 6.96 & -0.04 
            \end{tabular}
            \caption{my caption.}
            \label{myTable}
        \end{table}
```

However, this doesn't work in beamer. I am using the `\usepackage{xcolor}` package. Now, I found on [this blog](https://texblog.org/2018/01/15/color-table-series-part-2-xcolor-package/) that I should alter my documentclass to `\documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}` to use `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` and then everything should work. The problem here is that I am using a customized template and not the beamer template. Anyways, I can't get my head around this, it shouldn't be that complicated, should it?

Unfortunately, the error message that pops up is not helpful at all. It simply says: `Undefined control sequence \end{frame}`

Comment: You can try `PassOptionsToPackage{table}{xcolor}`.

Answer (score 3):

The package `beamer` load the `xcolor` package. If you like to add some option for `xcolor`, you should write this option between document class options:

```
\documentclass[table]{beamer} % <--- option "table"  is passed to "xcolor" pacage
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}
\newcolumntype{g}{>{\columncolor{Gray}}c}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{My colored table}
\begin{table}% table in beamer isn't float ...
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c|g|c|g|c|g}
        5.35 & 0.35 & 5.61 & -0.39 & 6.84 & -0.16 \\
        5.45 & 0.45 & 5.52 & -0.48 & 6.84 & -0.16 \\
        5.45 & 0.45 & 5.51 & -0.49 & 6.96 & -0.04 \\
        5.45 & 0.45 & 5.63 & -0.37 & 6.96 & -0.04
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{my caption.}
    \label{myTable}
\end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

it gives desired result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Because `tikzpicture` is well-adapted in the `beamer` class (they are writen by the same author Till Tantao), so it is posible to make a table as a `tikzpicture`. There is no need to load option `[table]`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
% I mimick the way of putting a row in a table
\newcommand{\putrow}[7]{
\path (0,#1) node{#2}
++(0:1) node{#3} ++(0:1) node{#4}
++(0:1) node{#5} ++(0:1) node{#6} ++(0:1) node{#7};
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Colored table}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=1.2,yscale=.5]
\begin{scope}[shift={(-.5,.5)}]
\foreach \i in {1,3,5} \fill[blue!20] (\i,0) rectangle +(1,-4);
\foreach \i in {1,...,6} \draw[blue] (\i,0)--+(-90:4);
\end{scope}
\putrow{0}{5.35}{0.35}{5.61}{-0.39}{6.84}{-0.16}
\putrow{-1}{5.45}{0.45}{5.52}{-0.48}{6.84}{-0.16}
\putrow{-2}{5.45}{0.45}{5.51}{-0.49}{6.96}{-0.04}
\putrow{-3}{5.45}{0.45}{5.63}{-0.37}{6.96}{-0.04}

\path (current bounding box.south) node[below=2mm,blue]
{My colored table as a tikzpicture};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```